# Add textearea in forms (Django)

Tags: python, django

Sorry for bad english, im from Argentina.

class Formulario_Contacto(forms.Form):

```
asunto=forms.CharField(label="Nombre", required=True)
email=forms.EmailField(label="Email", required=True)
mensaje=forms.CharField(label="Contenido", required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFvwJ.png)

Here is my views.py

def contacto(request):

```
#Si el metodo de request es POST, pasa esto, eso quiere decir el codigo de abajo
if request.method=="POST":

    miFormulario=Formulario_Contacto(request.POST)

    if miFormulario.is_valid():

        #Si el formulario es valido, hay que crear una variable donde almacenar la info que se ingreso, en este caso la llame formularioFinal
        formularioFinal=miFormulario.cleaned_data

        send_mail(formularioFinal["asunto"], formularioFinal["mensaje"],
        formularioFinal.get("email",""),["julian_regueira@hotmail.com"],)

        return render (request, "Contacto/gracias.html")
    
else:

    miFormulario=Formulario_Contacto()

return render(request, "Contacto/Form_Contacto.html", {"form":miFormulario})
```

I want to expand the text area in "mensaje"

Answer (score 1):

You can expand textarea by adding rows and columns.

```
mensaje=forms.CharField(label="Contenido", required=True, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 4, 'cols': 40}))
```